# Xml Parsing using jquery not working in IE

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I  use below code which works fine for me in FF but Problem in IE

```
  var lastName = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_ctl01_S3031AEBB_InputKeywords').keyup(function(event) {


     lastName =  $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_ctl01_S3031AEBB_InputKeywords').val();            
     if (lastName.length < 1) {$('#Main').hide(); HideImage();}
     else
     {
       search();

     }
});
});



function search() {


  var queryXML = "<QueryPacket Revision='1000'><Query><SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format></SupportedFormats><ResultProvider>SharepointSearch</ResultProvider><Context><QueryText type='MSSQLFT' language='en-us'>SELECT PREFERREDNAME,FirstName,LastName,JobTitle,Department,Email,WorkEmail,WorkPhone,Skills,PictureUrl,Path,Rank,MobilePhone FROM scope() where \"SCOPE\"='People' AND ((\"JobTitle\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Skills\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"LastName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"FirstName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Department\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%') OR (\"Email\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')  OR (\"WorkEmail\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%')  OR  (\"PreferredName\" LIKE '%" + lastName + "%'))</QueryText></Context><Range><StartAt>1</StartAt><Count>10</Count></Range><EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming><TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates><IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery><ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior><IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults><IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults><IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults></Query></QueryPacket>";
 var soapEnv =
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
       <soap:Body> \
         <Query xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search'> \
           <queryXml>" + escapeHTML(queryXML) + "</queryXml> \
         </Query> \
       </soap:Body> \
     </soap:Envelope>";
 $.ajax({
     url: "/_vti_bin/search.asmx",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "xml",
     data: soapEnv,
     complete: processResult,
     contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
 });       
 function processResult(xData, status) {
     $(xData.responseXML).find("QueryResult").each(function() {    

          var x = $("<xml>" + $(this).text() + "</xml>");
          x.find("Document").each(function() {
          var y = $("<xml>" + $(this).html() + "</xml>");
          var pname= "";
          var fname = "";
          var lname = "";
          var jobtitle = "";
          var mphone = "";
          var wemail = "";
          var workphone = "";
          var path = "";
          var purl = "";
          var title = "";                
          y.find("Property").each(function() {                  
             nameElement = $(this).find("Name").text();
             if (nameElement == "PREFERREDNAME") {
               pname = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "FIRSTNAME")
             {
                 fname = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "LASTNAME")
             {
                lname = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "JOBTITLE")
             {

                jobtitle = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "MOBILEPHONE")
             {
                mphone = $(this).find("Value").text(); 
             }
             else if(nameElement == "WORKEMAIL")
             {
                wemail = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "WORKPHONE")
             {
                workphone = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "PICTUREURL")
             {
                purl = $(this).find("Value").text();                   
             }
             else if(nameElement == "PATH")
             {
                path = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             else if(nameElement == "TITLE")
             {
                title = $(this).find("Value").text();
             }
             if (document.getElementById('AnsDiv') != null) {
                  $('#AnsDiv').remove();
             }   
          });                    



     });                    

     });
 }            
}

 function escapeHTML (str) {     
    return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');      
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem in IE is I am not able to get tag "Document" In below line of code

```
    x.find("Document").each(function() {
```

I got My solution. Just Do Xml Dom parsing using below code

```
  if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xData,"text/xml");
  }
 else{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xData); 
 }
```

also change this Line

```
  var y = ($.browser.msie) ? $("<xml>" + $(this).context.xml + "</xml>") : $("<xml>" + $(this).html() + "</xml>");
```