# Parsing SharePoint search.asmx results

Tags: jquery, xml, sharepoint

My query via jquery and search.asmx is successful and returning an xml result set. But the contents of the QueryResult node is escaped xml and I can't figure out how to parse it. ex:

```
<QueryResult>&lt;ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"&gt;&lt;Response domain="QDomain"&gt;&lt;Range&gt;&lt;StartAt&gt;1&lt;/StartAt&gt;&lt;Count&gt;5&lt;/Count&gt;&lt;TotalAvailable&gt;5&lt;/TotalAvailable&gt;&lt;Results&gt;&lt;Document xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document"&gt ... </QueryResult>
```

I'm trying to parse it this way but getting nowhere.

```
    function procSrchQry(xData, status){ 
    console.log("procSrchQry: start");
    $("#debugDiv2").text(xData.responseText);

    $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("QueryResult").each(function() {
      console.log("Found QueryResult");

      $("#debugDiv3").text( $(this).text()  );
       var x = $("<xml>" + $(this).text() + "</xml>"); // wrap text to make it XML      
       //traverse the xml to get the items
       x.find("Document").each(function() {
         console.log("Found Document node");
       });
    });   
  console.log("procSrchQry: end "); 
}
```

[V_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895281/xml-parsing-using-jquery-not-working-in-ie) is probably what I need to implement but I'm not sure how. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse XML string:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xData.responseText);
```

Then you can traverse XML using jQuery same way you work with html:

```
$(xmlDoc).find("TotalAvailable").text() // get TotalAvailable element value
```